# Encoding problems reading .bib into R using RefManageR

Tags: r, bibtex, blogdown

I'm trying to follow [this blog](https://lbusett.netlify.com/post/automatically-importing-publications-from-bibtex-to-a-hugo-academic-blog/) post to automatically generate `.md` files for each of my publications, for use in `blogdown`. The function in the post uses the package `RefManageR` to read entries from a BibTeX file, and creates a `.md` file for each entry.

My problem is that I cannot get `RefManageR` to read special characters correctly, even when I take pains to save the `.bib` with UTF-8 encoding and specify the encoding in the call to `ReadBib`.

As an example: I generate my `.bib` using Zotero, by exporting a collection to BibTeX with UTF-8 encoding. It gives me the following entry in my `.bib`:

```
@article{senior_pantropical_2017,
         title = {A pantropical analysis of the impacts of forest 
                 degradation and conversion on local temperature},
         volume = {7},
         issn = {2045-7758},
         doi = {10.1002/ece3.3262},
         number = {19},
         journal = {Ecology and Evolution},
         author = {Senior, Rebecca A. and Hill, Jane K. and González del 
                   Pliego, Pamela and Goode, Laurel K. and Edwards, David P.},
         month = oct,
         year = {2017},
         pages = {7897--7908}
}
```

As you can see, there is an accent on one of the author names (González del Pliego). I check the encoding by opening in RStudio (where the characters are displayed correctly) and to be doubly sure I do 'Save with encoding'. No matter what I do, when I read the `.bib` into R like so:

```
ReadBib('path/to/refs.bib', .Encoding = "UTF-8")
```

It always shows up like this:

```
[1] R. A. Senior, J. K. Hill, P. GonzÃ¡lez del Pliego, et al. “A pantropical analysis of the impacts of forest degradation and conversion on local temperature”. In: _Ecology and Evolution_7.19 (Oct. 2017), pp. 7897-7908. ISSN: 2045-7758. DOI: 10.1002/ece3.3262.
```

Why is the á appearing as Ã¡? I've tried various packages and functions (`RefManageR::ReadBib`, `bibtex::read.bib` and `bib2df::bib2df`) and various different ways of specifying and checking the encoding. I can't typeset the characters manually (e.g. `{\'a}`) because some of my publications have a *lot* of authors. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: UPDATE: for now I can't figure this out so I am manually typesetting the characters, although that is still a bit iffy for some characters (e.g. í )

Answer (score 2):

I use `bib2df::bib2df()` to read UTF-8 encoded bibtex file.

```
options(encoding="UTF-8")
bib_df <- bib2df("publications.bib")
```

and it works for me.